# how to get multiple distance route results for single destination from google api call?

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, location

how to get multiple distance route results for single destination from google api call?

starting point and ending point i have to find the distance between them. i have to display the shortest and middle and longest distance for only one destination(ending point).
it has any API provided to me.

Please help me

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the current location latitude,longitude and destination latitude,longitude in below url. You will get the result.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.4444,78.4666&destination=17.4393,78.4056&units=imperial&alternatives=true&sensor=false

Comment: @RamsChowdary i'm getting multiple routes only first time when i call the api, after that it returns only one route? and what is other possible values of request parameter 'units'?